# Configure terraform with aws without user credentials

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-iam, terraform-provider-aws

Trying to configure aws from terraform. Running terraform from ec2. Have attached **AmazonEC2FullAccess** policy to the role attached to ec2.

I don't have access and secret keys. Using keys for aws cli and terraform is not allowed. I need to use existing role to configure to aws and create resources using it.

Getting below error when using AmazonEC2FullAccess policy with ec2.

```
[ec2-user@ip-1*-1*-1*-2** terraform]$ terraform plan
╷
│ Error: error configuring Terraform AWS Provider: no valid credential sources for Terraform AWS Provider found.
│
│ Please see https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws
│ for more information about providing credentials.
│
│ Error: failed to refresh cached credentials, no EC2 IMDS role found, operation error ec2imds: GetMetadata, request send failed, Get "http://1**.***.***.***/latest/meta-data/iam/security-credentials/": proxyconnect tcp: dial tcp 1*.*.*.*:8***: i/o timeout
│
│
│   with provider["registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws"],
│   on main.tf line 17, in provider "aws":
│   17: provider "aws" {
│
```

Resource vpc file :-

```
[ec2-user@ip-1*.1*.1*.*** terraform]$ cat vpc.tf
resource "aws_vpc" "main" {
  cidr_block = "1*.*.*.*/16"
}
```

main.tf file :-

```
[ec2-user@ip-1*.1*.1*.*** terraform]$ cat main.tf
terraform {
  required_providers {
    aws = {
    source  = "hashicorp/aws"
    version = "~> 4.39.0"
    }
  }
  required_version = ">= 1.3.0"
}

provider "aws" {
  region                = var.aws_region
  #role_arn             =var.aws_role_arn
}
```

Also tried using role_arn in main.tf it gives following error :-

```
│ Error: Unsupported argument
│
│   on main.tf line 19, in provider "aws":
│   19:   role_arn              =var.aws_role_arn
│
│ An argument named "role_arn" is not expected here.
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: I think you first need to configure a named profile using `aws configure` but specify a role ARN and `credential_source = Ec2InstanceMetadata`. Then in the `provider` block you can reference the named profile you created. More info here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-role.html

Comment: This error: "Error: failed to refresh cached credentials, no EC2 IMDS role found, operation error ec2imds: GetMetadata, request send failed, Get "http://1**.***.***.***/latest/meta-data/iam/security-credentials/": proxyconnect tcp: dial tcp 1*.*.*.*:8***: i/o timeout" (you didn't need to * those Ip addresses out, it's the same IP, 169.254.169.254 on every EC2 instance)  Indicates that the metadata service isn't working on your EC2 instance. Are you running this Terraform code from a docker image on the EC2 instance or something? You need to figure out what is wrong with your EC2 metadata.